# Loading UIWebView from UITableView works only 1st time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, rubymotion

I'm using rubymotion with [promotion](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion) framework to develop my first iOS application. I have a table view (inside navigation controller), tapping on a table cell opens new screen with web view that loads local html file. The problem is that the web view is displayed only for 1st time I load it. When I go back (navigation controller) and tap on any cell again it opens new screen, but web view is not displayed. Web views delegate method is triggered, so it loads it, but I see only black screen (with navigation bar).

Here's the code for a screen with web view:

```
class XXXDetailScreen < ProMotion::Screen

  attr_accessor :screen_title

  def on_load
    XXXDetailScreen.title = self.screen_title

    @web_view = add_element UIWebView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
    @web_view.delegate = self
    @web_view.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    @web_view.scrollView.bounces = false

    @web_view.loadRequest(NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('index', ofType: 'html', inDirectory: 'html'))))
  end

  def webView(inWeb, shouldStartLoadWithRequest: inRequest, navigationType: inType)
    true
  end
end
```

The screen above is opened with this code:

```
def tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    open GalleryDetailScreen.new(screen_title: @data[indexPath.row][:title]), hide_tab_bar: true
end
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the creators of ProMotion. It's usually better to use the `will_appear` method to set up view elements as the on_load will usually fire too early to get your view's proper `bounds`. However, if you do load it in the `will_appear` you need to make sure you only instantiate the web view once (`will_appear` fires every time you switch to that screen).

I'll demonstrate:

```
class XXXDetailScreen < ProMotion::Screen

  attr_accessor :screen_title

  def on_load
    XXXDetailScreen.title = self.screen_title
  end

  def will_appear
    add_element draw_web_view
  end

  def draw_web_view
    @web_view ||= begin
      v = UIWebView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
      v.delegate = self
      v.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
      v.scrollView.bounces = false

      v.loadRequest(NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('index', ofType: 'html', inDirectory: 'html'))))
      v
    end
  end

  def webView(inWeb, shouldStartLoadWithRequest: inRequest, navigationType: inType)
    true
  end
end
```

---

As a side note, you really don't need the `:screen_title` accessor. Just do this when loading it:

```
open GalleryDetailScreen.new(title: @data[indexPath.row][:title]), hide_tab_bar: true
```

Comment: Jamon, thanks for your help and for your work on ProMotion! It makes RubyMotion development much more enjoyable :)